# Navigation Bar obscures bottom elements in my app on Android 13

Tags: android, android-13

There is some specific area at the bottom of the screen in Android 13:

[image]

On the picture above it is transparent, but on the picture below it is not:

[image]

How do I control its behaviour in my app? Does app manifest affect this somehow?

Currently I have the following `android:theme` element in my app manifest:

```
    <activity android:name="com.myapp.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|uiMode|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|layoutDirection|locale|fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|mcc|mnc|density"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

where `AppTheme` is defined in `apptheme.xml` as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

and this specific bottom area is black and obscures the bottom elements of my app.

I need to make my app not overlap with this area (I already figured out that the area is bottom Navigation Bar).

**EDIT1**

My first idea was that it is something related to `FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS` flag, but this flag is not set. When I add the following code:

```
    android.view.Window window = getWindow();
    
    if ((getWindow().getAttributes().flags & android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS) != 0)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "The flag is set.");
    }
    else
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "The flag is NOT set.");
    }
```

my activity `onCreate()` I get `The flag is NOT set.`.

Also tried this:

```
    window.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
        android.view.View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE |
        android.view.View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

but without a success.

My device is Pixed 2 XL emulator:

[image]

**EDIT2**

Finally I was able to make Navigation Bar transparent with the following code:

```
    android.view.Window window = getWindow();
    
    window.addFlags(android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);

    window.setNavigationBarColor(0x00000000);
```

but I have no idea on how to make it not overlap with my app window.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code in the main()

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
  const SystemUiOverlayStyle(systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.transparent),
);
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.edgeToEdge);
```